# Mother in law leaving to go to home country - wants to visit Jordan - is a visa needed?

Tags: visa

Mother in law in June was given a green card (IR5 type - mother of a daughter having a US citizen) back in June.  She visited us and plans to return to Iraq sometime in November.  She has another daughter in the country of Jordan who is staying there temporarily.  Since the country of Jordan neighbors Iraq and she is headed to Iraq she thought it would be nice to visit her other daughter who lives in Jordan.  She plans to stay two weeks in Jordan.

Simple question is does she need to obtain a Visa to go to Jordan?  What are the steps taken if she does need one?  Or is this not needed?  Just as an FYI she is an Iraqi Citizen and as mentioned has a green card (IR5 type).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, she will need a visa; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Jordan.  I see from your profile that you live in Michigan; there is an honorary consulate in Lathrup, MI; see https://www.passportsandvisas.com/embassy-consulate/jordan.  I do not know whether they process visa applications, but the Jordanian visa is an ink stamp with handwritten annotations, so it seems likely.

I generally prefer to use government sources, but I wasn't able to find a good source from a Jordanian government site.

With respect to her green card, it doesn't make a difference.  There are some countries (notably including Canada) that give visa exemptions to green card holders in some circumstances, but Jordan does not appear to be among them.

Comment: Can she obtain the visa directly in the Jordanian airport in Amman or is it too late at that time?

Comment: @JonH Iraq is not on the list of countries whose citizens are eligible for visa on arrival, so she is not going to be able to board a plane bound for Jordan without a visa, let alone get a visa at the airport in Amman.

Comment: But when she was in transit she came through jordan without a visa. So why is it required now?

Comment: @JonH in most airports in the world, one can do an international-to-international transit without passing through immigration control.  So it's required now because she plans to stay in Jordan and pass through immigration control.

Comment: Strange when i go to the site you posted it asks for citizen of which country and i pick iraq. Then i click jordan for the country to ovtain a visa and the grid shows no visa application. Either the web page is broken or iraqi citizens cannot get a jordan visa.

Comment: @JonH the site I posted is unofficial.  I would not worry too much about that.  Call the consulate and ask them.  If you can't reach the honorary consulate, try the others until you get an answer.